# A basic and short question of linear dependency

Tags: linear-algebra

Why are the vectors $v_1,...,v_k$ linearly dependent if any one of them is zero?  If any subset of them is linearly dependent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$v_1, \ldots, v_k$ are linearly dependent vectors if
$$
\exists (\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_k) \neq (0, \ldots, 0), \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i v_i = 0
$$
Suppose $v_1=0$, since $(1, 0, \ldots, 0) \neq (0, \ldots, 0)$ and $$1 \cdot v_1 + 0 \cdot v_2 + \cdots + 0 \cdot v_k =0$$ we have that $v_1 \ldots, v_k$ are linearly dependent.

Can you apply a similar method for the second question?

Comment: Yes, I can. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 4):

This follows from the definition of LI. A set of vectors is LI if we can find a **non-trivial** (not all zero coefficients) solution to the following:
$$c_1\mathbf{v}_1+c_2+\mathbf{v}_2+\dotsb +c_k\mathbf{v}_k=\mathbf{0}.$$
Say if $\mathbf{v_1}=\mathbf{0}$, then we can choose $c_1=1$ and rest of the $c_i$'s as $0$ which gives a non-trivial solution, hence LD.

Similarly if a subset was LD, we can choose coefficients to have a non-trivial solution.

Comment: Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

$$ *** $$
Let the set of vectors S = {$ v_1,v_2,v_3, \ldots, v_k $}, be linearly dependent.

Then by definition of linear dependence, there exists scalars {$c_1,c_2,c_3,\ldots,c_k$} (not all zero) such that

$$ c_1\mathbf{v}_1 + c_2\mathbf{v}_2 + c_3\mathbf{v}_3 + \dotsb + c_k\mathbf{v}_k=\mathbf{0}.$$

Let the vector $v_1 = \mathbf{0}$ and rest be non-zero, then,

$$ c_1\mathbf{0} + c_2\mathbf{v}_2 + c_3\mathbf{v}_3 + \dotsb + c_k\mathbf{v}_k=\mathbf{0}.$$

If all scalars, {$c_1,c_2,c_3,\ldots,c_k$} = 0, i.e. $c_1=0$ , $c_2=0$ , $c_3=0$ , $\ldots$, $c_k=0$, then,

$$ 0.\mathbf{0} + 0.\mathbf{v}_2 + 0.\mathbf{v}_3 + \dotsb + 0.\mathbf{v}_k=\mathbf{0}.$$

Now if $c_1=1$ and {$c_2,c_3,\ldots,c_k$} = 0, i.e. $c_2=0$ , $c_3=0$ , $\ldots$, $c_k=0$, then,

$$ 1.\mathbf{0} + 0.\mathbf{v}_2 + 0.\mathbf{v}_3 + \dotsb + 0.\mathbf{v}_k=\mathbf{0}.$$

Even if $c_1=n$ and {$c_2,c_3,\ldots,c_k$} = 0, i.e. $c_2=0$ , $c_3=0$ , $\ldots$, $c_k=0$, then,

$$ n.\mathbf{0} + 0.\mathbf{v}_2 + 0.\mathbf{v}_3 + \dotsb + 0.\mathbf{v}_k=\mathbf{0}.$$

$$ *** $$

**Therefore**, a set of scalars (not all zero) exists i.e. { ($1,0,\ldots,0$), ($2,0,\ldots,0$), $\ldots$, ($n,0,\ldots,0$) }

From this proof: If there exists even **one zero vector** in the set, then the set becomes **linearly dependent**, because keeping other coefficients as zero, the zero vector coefficient can be any non-zero value.

$$ *** $$